# pathshorten: all but containing directory

Tags: plugin-airline

I display the current file name and path using:

```
let g:airline_section_c = '%{pathshorten(expand(''%:f''))}'
```

Which results in, for example:

```
/h/b/.c/n/init.vim
```

This keeps things tidy. However, it would be slightly more useful to have the containing folder name visible. So:

```
/h/b/.c/nvim/init.vim
```

The docs for `pathshorten` seem to suggest that this isn't configurable, and I haven't been able to think of a better solution short of writing my own. Does a viable alternative exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `pathshorten()` on the results of `expand('%:h')` to shorten only the path up to the containing folder (the head).
For a path of `/home/dev/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
expand('%:h')              -> /home/dev/.vim/ftplugin
pathshorten(expand('%:h')) -> /h/d/.v/ftplugin
```

Then, you can use `expand('%:t')` to get just the tail of the path (in this example, `c.vim`) and concatenate with the shortened head:

```
pathshorten(expand('%:h')) . '/' . expand('%:t') -> /h/d/.v/ftplugin/c.vim
```

---

This will work 99% of the time, and you could stop there and probably never encounter the other 1%:

**What if the only component of the path is the tail?**

---

Take for instance the path `/foo`. The result of the above for this path would be `//foo` (due to the `/` concatenated between the shortened head `/` and the
tail `foo`). This is a contrived example, sure, but for the sake of completeness you could check if `expand('%:h') == '/'` (indicative of our edge case) when adding the shortened head before the tail of the path.
In this snippet, I'm using a conditional expression:

```
(expand('%:h') == '/' ? '' : pathshorten(expand('%:h'))) . '/' .  expand('%:t')
```

This will now correctly show the path `/foo`, covering our edge case.

---

This is kind of hard to understand at a glance though, especially within a statusline item with `%{}`.
It may be better to move this to it's own function, where the logic can be expressed more clearly, as well as decluttering our variable assignment:

```
function! CondensedPath() abort
    if expand(':h') == '/'
        return '/' . expand('%:t')
    else
        return pathshorten(expand('%:h')) . '/' . expand('%:t')
    endif
endfunction

let g:airline_section_c='%{CondensedPath()}'
```

Comment: Outstanding answer, very thorough! I'll add for the sake of completeness that, had I consulted `:h expand` rather than `:h pathshorten`, that would've led me to the list of modifiers and `:h` for 'head'.